# Godot: how to connect button signal via script

Tags: godot

I have a button that I am instancing every time the main scene appears, and I want to connect it's pressed signal each time it is instanced via script. I am really lost on how to do this, I have looked at multiple things and it still does not really make sense. Could somebody help me?

Comment: Is this Godot 3 or Godot 4? What did you try and what happened? It is possible to connect signals from code, but chances are you are looking at the wrong examples, except I don't know which are the correct examples for you case just from your description.

Answer (score 5):

Godot 4:

```
var button = Button.new()
button.connect("pressed", _yourFunction.bind(someVar))
```

Answer (score 3):

Godot 4.1.1

```
var button = Button.new()
button.pressed.connect(self._button_pressed.bind(some_variable_or_value))
...
func _button_pressed(arg):
    print("_button_pressed: ", arg)
```